# How do I get my Dock to appear on the left in Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: 20.10

How do I get my Dock to appear on the left in Ubuntu 20?

I've set it in Preferences but it seems to be being ignored.

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/devices releases that can use *snap* packages only.   Your tag however is for a *standard* deb based release, unlike your title.  Please clarify/correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the dock comes to the left by default.

In your case, it looks as if you have the extension "Dash to panel" installed. That combines the dash and the panel into the area on the bottom by default.

To solve your issue, disable the extension "Dash to panel" and (re)enable the extension "Ubuntu Dock".